# Filtering data by start date and end date in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel consisting of start date and the end date in columns.

Now via this code I can filter out the start date and the end date:

```
       df['QC END DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['QC END DATE'])
       mask = (df['QC START DATE'] >= startdateEn.get()) & (df['QC END DATE'] <= endateEn.get())
       df = df.loc[mask]
```

but I am not happy with the filtering as it just gives me only the date in between of these two:

for eg in pandas if I use start date - 5/3/2019 and end date as - 5/13/2019

it excludes the entries having start date of 4/25/2019 and end date - 5/10/2019.

I want such entries to appear if the entry is has an end date between the start and the end date

What should I do?

Comment: What does `startdateEn.get()` return? Is it a string? A timestamp?...

Comment: 5/13/2019 , MMDDYYYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you want to find overlapping intervals.

that is - your data has start-end, and your "query" has start-end,
and you want all entries whose interval overlap (even slightly) with your "query" interval.

try this:

```py
df['QC END DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['QC END DATE'])
df['QC START DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['QC START DATE'])
df = df[(((df['QC START DATE'] >= startdateEn.get()) & (df['QC START DATE'] <= endateEn.get())) | ((df['QC END DATE'] >= startdateEn.get()) & (df['QC END DATE'] <= endateEn.get())))]
```

This way we look for entries whose `QC START DATE` or their `QC END DATE` is between `startdateEn` and `endateEn`, meaning they overlapped

Comment: I tried it but it throws me an error :File "C:/Quality Checker/hey.py", line 74, in getreport
    mask = ((df['QC START DATE'] >= startdateEn.get() & df['QC START DATE'] <= endateEn.get()) | (

Comment: @ShernelMonteiro I've edited my answer a little, could you try now?

Comment: Nah does not work : typ=type(y).__name__))
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: I think I got my brackets mixed up a it

Comment: Is there something to do with the bracket dividing them "|"??

Comment: yes, the `|` is a an `OR` just like `&` is an `AND`. I edited again (with more brackets, surrounding each condition). could you please try once more?

Comment: Works like charm! You genius :)

Comment: Thanks, sorry it took so many tries, all the `(((` and `)))` confused me :P

Comment: Hello, the code you provided helps with the start date but when I filter the end date it gives me results exceeding the end date .e.g.  - if my end date is 5/29/2019 it gives me results till 5/31/2019. I just want the results to remain within the end date